# Angular.js - get http.get(array) to variable for filter

Tags: angularjs, database, variables

i just want to pass the array returning from a http.get() to an variable, to filter them in the factory. (similar to the chats-example from ionic)

Here is my factory:

```
.factory('pizzaService', function($http) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      // Return promise (async callback)
      return $http.get("http://localhost/soundso/www/php/load_Pizzas.php");
    },
    get: function(pizzaID) {
      for (var i = 0; i < pizzas.length; i++) {
        if (pizzas[i].id === parseInt(pizzaID)) {
          return pizzas[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

In the get function, it doesn't know what pizzas is, because the is nothing like "var pizzas = http.get(...)", but this doesn't work.
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The $http.get method return a future object. To get the response content, you must define a success callback and store the result in a variable. It would give you something like this (I did not test it):

```
.factory('pizzaService', function($http) {
  var pizzas;
  // your data are got from the URL only once when the factory is invoked. may be moved elsewhere if the Url is invoked several times
  function getDataFromServer(){
    $http.get("http://localhost/soundso/www/php/load_Pizzas.php").
      success(function(data, status) {
        pizzas=data;
      }).error(function(data, status) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      });
  }
  //the first call on factory initialisation initialize the pizzas variable
  getDataFromServer();
  return {
    getAll : function(){
      return pizzas;
    },
    get: function(pizzaID) {
      for (var i = 0; i < pizzas.length; i++) {
        if (pizzas[i].id === parseInt(pizzaID)) {
          return pizzas[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

You may also want to adding an extra method to refresh the data from the server, i.e: launch the $http request on demand:

```
...
return {
    refresh : function(){
      getDataFromServer();
    },
    getAll : ...
    get : ...
};
```

Comment: i know, what you mean. But this way, it doesn't work. And how can i return all?

Comment: It seems like it is more a design problem than a technical one. The design problem here is when to you need to refresh th epizzas variables with data from the server. With the proposition above, you can move the $http.get into a function return by the factory. But with this kind of design, you will have to ensure that the data are loaded (by calling this new function) before to call the get function. Otherwise, you won't have any data loaded into the pizzas variable before applying the filter (the get method)